# Playwright before each for all spec files

Tags: javascript, typescript, automated-tests, playwright, playwright-test

I am very new to Playwright. Due to my test suites, I need to login into my application before running each test. Inside a single spec file that is easy, I can simply call `test.beforeEach`. My issue is: I need to before the login before each test of each spec file.

```
test.describe('Test', () => {
    //I need to make the code inside this beforeEach a exported 
    //function to call inside the before each of every spec file I have
    test.beforeEach(async ({ page }) => {
        await page.goto('/login');
        await page.click('text=Log in with Google account');
        await page.fill('id=identifierId', LoginAutomationCredentials.USER);
        await page.click('button[jsname="LgbsSe"]');
        await page.fill('input[type="password"]', LoginAutomationCredentials.PASSWORD);
        await page.click('button[jsname="LgbsSe"]');
        const otp = authenticator.generateToken(LoginAutomationCredentials.TOKEN);
        await page.fill('id=totpPin', otp);
        await page.click('button[jsname="LgbsSe"]');
    });

    it('Some description', async ({ page }) => {
        await page.goto('/foo');
        const dateFilter = await page.inputValue('input[placeholder="2011/03/02"]');
        expect(dateFilter).toBe('2021/12/07');
    });
});
```

I tried simply taking that code and and making it a function inside a separate .ts file and then importing it, but I figured the context is needed in order to do this. This is probably something every tester that uses playwright knows and uses regularly, however, I did not find anything on the subject.

How can I avoid copying the entire code of `beforeEach` and pasting it to all my spec files? How can I make it a function and call it whenever I want?

Comment: Why dont you just use global setup and reuse authentication?
You could also try with fixtures, create login fixture and pass that instead of page fixture.

Comment: Global setup is the way to go : https://playwright.dev/docs/test-advanced#global-setup-and-teardown

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use fixtures.

fixture.js:

```
const base = require('@playwright/test')
const newTest = base.test.extend({
    login: async({page}, use) => {
        await login();
        await use(page); //runs test here
        //logic after test
    }
})
exports.newTest = newTest
exports.expect = newTest.expect
```

Then in your tests:

```
const {newTest} = require('fixture.js')
newTest('mytest', async ({login}) => {
    //test logic
    login.goto(''); // using login here since I pass it as page in the fixture.
})
```

Answer (score 4):

Fixtures is the right way, but there is a better option than having to remember to use `login` instead of `page` when you want to login.  This is how I do it...

First I have this in `playwright/src/index.ts` where I setup all the fixtures for my project:

```js
import { test as base_test, expect } from 'playwright_test';

type TestFixtures = {
  user: string;
};

export const test = base_test.extend<TestFixtures>( {
  user : 'default-user@example.com',
  async context( { user, context, request }, use ) {
    // This makes a REST request to the backend to get a JWT token
    // and then stores that token in the browsers localStorage,
    // but you could replace this with whatever makes sense for auth
    // in your app
    if ( user ) {
      const content = await getAuthScript( user, request );
      await context.addInitScript( { content } );
    }
    await use( context );
  },
} );

/**
 * This makes a REST request to the backend to get a JWT token
 * and then stores that token in the browsers localStorage,
 * but you could replace this with whatever makes sense for auth
 * in your app.
 */
async function getAuthScript( user, request ) {
  const res = await request.post( '/api/test/auth', { data : { user } } );
  const { token } = await res.json();
  return `window.localStorage.setItem( 'jwt-token', "${token}" );`;
}

export { test, expect }
```

I also make sure that `playwright/tsconfig.json` includes this:

```json
{
  "extends": "../path/to/base/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noEmit": true,
    "paths": {
      "~": [ "./src" ],
      "~*": [ "./src/*" ]
    },
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "rootUrl": ".",
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "test/**/*.ts"
  ],
}
```

Now every test will automatically login as `default-user@example.com`, but if you need a test to login as a different user all you need to do in that test file is:

```js
import { test, expect } from '~';

test.use( { user : 'somebody-else@example.com' } );
test( 'can login as somebody-else', async ( { page } ) => {
  // Run your tests here...
} );
```

Answer (score 4):

There two aproaches:

## Use `project dependency`

Form `Playwright 1.31` with `project dependency` you can set test what will be executed before any other tests and pass i.e. browser storage between tests.

See working and tested example (entering google search page and accepting policies, and then entering this page again with cookies):

**playwright.config.ts**:

```js
import { PlaywrightTestConfig } from "@playwright/test";
import path from "path";

//here you save session
export const STORAGE_STATE = path.join(__dirname, 'login.json')
    
const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
  timeout: 10 * 1000,
  expect: {
    timeout: 3 * 1000,
  },
  testDir: './tests',
  use:{
    baseURL: 'https://google.com',
    trace: 'retain-on-failure',
    video: 'retain-on-failure',
  },
  // here we set main project and dependent one
  projects: [
    {
      name: 'login',
      grep: /@login/
    },
    {
      name: 'depend e2e',
      grep: /@e2e/,
      dependencies: ['login'],
      use: {
        storageState: STORAGE_STATE
      }
    }

  ]
}; 

export default config;
```

**tests/example.spec.ts**:

```js
import { test} from '@playwright/test';
import { STORAGE_STATE } from '../playwright.config';
    
test('login to service @login', async({page}) => {
  await page.goto('/');
  // below example is to reject cookies from google
  await page.waitForLoadState('domcontentloaded');
  await page.keyboard.press('Tab');
  await page.keyboard.press('Enter');
  await page.getByRole('menuitem', { name: "English (United States)" }).press('Enter');
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Reject all' }).click();
  
  // Save storage:
  await page.context().storageState({path: STORAGE_STATE})
})

test('logged in test @e2e', async ({page}) => {
  await page.goto('/');
  await page.waitForLoadState('domcontentloaded');
  // BOOM - you are in!
  // Screenshot shows that settings regarding cookies were saved
  await page.screenshot({ path: 'screenshot.png' })
})
```

Video with example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PI50YAPTAs4&t=286s

In above example I'm using tags to identify tests: https://playwright.dev/docs/test-annotations#tag-tests

## Use `fixtures`

Let test entering google search page and accepting policies

In file `fixtures.ts`:

```js
import { test as base } from "@playwright/test";

export const test = base.extend({
  page: async ({ baseURL, page }, use) => {
    // We have a few cases where we need our app to know it's running in Playwright.
    // This is inspired by Cypress that auto-injects window.Cypress.
    await page.addInitScript(() => {
      (window as any).Playwright = true;
    });

   await page.goto("/");
   // below example is to reject cookies from google
   await page.waitForLoadState("domcontentloaded");
   await page.keyboard.press("Tab");
   await page.keyboard.press("Enter");
   await page
     .getByRole("menuitem", { name: "English (United States)" })
     .press("Enter");
   await page.getByRole("button", { name: "Reject all" }).click();

    use(page);
  },
});
export { expect } from "@playwright/test";
```

And then in test use new `test` object instead importing it form `"@playwright/test"`

```js
import { test, expect } from "../fixture";

test("logged in test @e2e", async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto("/");
  await page.waitForLoadState("domcontentloaded");
  // BOOM - you are in!
  // Screenshot shows that it works
  await page.screenshot({ path: "screenshot.png" });
});
```

Inspired by: https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/9468#issuecomment-1403214587

If you need example with global request intercepting see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76234592/1266040

Answer (score 0):

I think [global setup and teardown](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-advanced#global-setup-and-teardown) might be the best solution for logging in before tests.

Here's a sketch to show what this might look like on your code, based on the docs (untested).

`global-setup.ts`:

```
import {chromium, FullConfig} from "@playwright/test";

async function globalSetup(config: FullConfig) {
  const browser = await chromium.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  // do your login:
  await page.goto("/login");
  await page.click("text=Log in with Google account");
  await page.fill(
    "id=identifierId",
    LoginAutomationCredentials.USER
  );
  await page.click('button[jsname="LgbsSe"]');
  await page.fill(
    'input[type="password"]',
    LoginAutomationCredentials.PASSWORD
  );
  await page.click('button[jsname="LgbsSe"]');
  const otp = authenticator.generateToken(
    LoginAutomationCredentials.TOKEN
  );
  await page.fill("id=totpPin", otp);
  await page.click('button[jsname="LgbsSe"]');

  // see below for further discussion
  // const { baseURL, storageState } = config.projects[0].use;
  // await page.context().storageState({ path: storageState as string });
  // await browser.close();
}

export default globalSetup;
```

`playwright.config.ts`:

```
import {defineConfig} from "@playwright/test";

export default defineConfig({
  globalSetup: require.resolve("./global-setup"),
  use: {
    baseURL: "http://localhost:3000/",
    storageState: "state.json",
  },
});
```

`tests/foo.spec.js`:

```js
test.describe("Test", () => {
  it("Some description", async ({page}) => {
    await page.goto("/foo");
    const dateFilter = await page.inputValue(
      'input[placeholder="2011/03/02"]'
    );
    expect(dateFilter).toBe("2021/12/07");
  });
});
```

Now, in the original Playwright example, their `globalSetup` function writes to storage state:

```js
// ...
  await page.getByText('Sign in').click();
  await page.context().storageState({ path: storageState as string });
  await browser.close();
// ...
```

But your code doesn't. You might need to do so as the last line of your `globalSetup` function, then call `await browser.close()` to save and carry those tokens between one browser session and the next.

They're pulling this `storageState` string from `const { baseURL, storageState } = config.projects[0].use;` so that it doesn't need to be hardcoded in multiple places. See their docs for a full example.

---

Once you have that working and you've written your `state.json` file, you may want to skip running future logins if the tokens are still valid. You can do so with the following modifications to
`global-setup.ts`:

```
import fs from "node:fs/promises";

// ...

async function exists(path: string): Promise<boolean> {
  return !!(await fs.stat(path).catch(() => false));
}

async function globalSetup(config: FullConfig) {
  const {storageState} = config.projects[0].use;

  if (await exists(storageState)) {
    return;
  }

  const browser = await chromium.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  // do your login:
  await page.goto("/login");

  // ...
}

// ...
```

Most likely, `state.json` should be added to your project's `.gitignore`.