# afterEach for multiple spec files

Tags: typescript, playwright-typescript

I'm looking for a way to run some common code across tests in multiple spec files in Playwright typescript. My particular case is wanting to upload test results based on `testInfo`. I'm aware that [fixtures can be used for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70262213/playwright-before-each-for-all-spec-files), but this is not ideal. With fixtures, I need to specify the fixture for every test, and in my case I don't need to reference the fixture within my tests. This makes it easy to not include the fixture on new tests, and accidentally remove it with lint clean up on existing tests.

I have seen that importing files that include `beforeAll` or `afterAll` will run that code as expected. But doing the same with `beforeEach` or `afterEach` only runs that code once, instead of once for each test.

Is there a way to get functionality like `beforeEach` or `afterEach` for multiple spec files without having to add superfluous code to each test?

Comment: I did a little exploring on this. I'm not finding in my simple cases that `beforeAll` or `afterAll` are necessarily used when importing a file. The cases I saw were that was happening was not something I wrote. So I may have missed so details that causes it. But I did just find `globalSetup` and `globalTeardown` which are better suited to that case. But there doesn't seem to be anything for the `*Each` cases.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found to do this is to have common file that you import into each test file and call. This works well for `beforeEach` and `afterEach`. However, `beforeAll` and `afterAll` applies to each spec file. So each will be called once for each spec file, and not for the whole group. If you want those to run once for the whole set of specs a better option is using [`globalSetup` and `globalTeardown`](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-advanced#global-setup-and-teardown).

Common file:

```
import { test } from '@playwright/test';

export function setupGlobalHooks() {
  test.beforeAll(() => {
    // Before all tests
  });

  test.beforeEach(() => {
    // Before each test
  });

  test.afterAll(() => {
    // After all tests
  });

  test.afterEach(() => {
    // After each test
  });
}
```

A spec file:

```
import { test } from "@playwright/test";
import { setupGlobalHooks } from "./global";

setupGlobalHooks();
...
```

Alternatively, you could also have a set of shared functions that you call in each specs `beforeEach` and `afterEach`. But I like the above a little better as it's very obvious if you're missing the common hooks.

There is a [feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/9468) written. So hopefully there will be a better solution. Note, the solution in the second post appears to work, but fails if the number of workers is 1. Both the `*All` and `*Each` hooks will only run for the first spec run.