# Playwright - beforeEach for all the files in the suite, or mock responses to all tests

Tags: javascript, configuration, mocking, playwright

I've seen i can mock a response in Playwright using the `page.route`

```
await page.route('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all', async route => {
  const json = {
    message: { 'test_breed': [] }
  };
  await route.fulfill({ json });
});
```

That's awesome, but can i do it to all tests without need to call it in each file?
Is there a mock configuration in the `playwright.config` or something similar?

Comment: What is your use case? What are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: @VishalAggarwal i have a interceptor(s) that i want to run before each test

Answer (score 2):

U can use fixture for it.
Let test intercepting `https://httpbin.org/uuid` what normally returns `{"uuid": "03840957-0386-498b-bd29-5c9cdbd84ed9"}`

In file `fixtures.ts`:

```js
    import { test as base } from "@playwright/test";
    
    export const test = base.extend({
      page: async ({ baseURL, page }, use) => {
        // We have a few cases where we need our app to know it's running in Playwright.
        // This is inspired by Cypress that auto-injects window.Cypress.
        await page.addInitScript(() => {
          (window as any).Playwright = true;
        });
    
        // Here we can enable logging of all requests, which is useful to see sometimes.
        // We also block some unnecessary third-party requests which speeds up the tests.
        await page.route(`https://httpbin.org/uuid`, async (route) => {
          const json = {
            message: 'my stuff ',
          };
          await route.fulfill({ json });
        });
    
        use(page);
      },
    });
    export { expect } from "@playwright/test";
```

And then in test use new `test` object instead importing it form `"@playwright/test"`

```js
import { test, expect } from "../fixture";

test("check if fixture working @fix", async ({ page }) => {
  // Act
  await page.goto("https://httpbin.org/uuid");
  const res = page.locator("pre");
  console.log(await res.innerText());

  // Assert
  await expect(res).toHaveText(`{"message":"my stuff "}`);
});
```

Finlay after running test:

```bash
Running 1 test using 1 worker
[chromium] › example.spec.ts:3:5 › check if fixture working @fix
{"message":"my stuff "}
  1 passed (1.1s)
```

Inspired by: https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/9468#issuecomment-1403214587

Answer (score 1):

found the answer [here](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/9468).
it's seems currently there is no way `beforeEach` to all tests like in jest or other frameworks. the issue is still active so we can only hope...

at this time the suggestion is to have beforeEach on each file:

```
import { sharedBeforeEachFunction } from './hooks.mjs'

test.beforeEach(sharedBeforeEachFunction);

test('Login Sanity Test @smoke', async ({ page }) => {
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[(Found here)](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/9468#issuecomment-942475009), You can create a file similar to a fixture where you put any hooks that you want your spec to implement, then re-export `test` from that file to your spec. EG:

```
// testWithBeforeEach.ts
import { test } from '@playwright/test'

test.beforeEach(() => {
    console.log('beforeEach');
})

export default test
```

```
// mytest-1.spec.ts
import { test } from './testWithBeforeEach'

test('should work 1', async ({ page }) => {
})
```

```
// mytest2.spec.ts
import { test } from './testWithBeforeEach'

test('should work 2', async ({ page }) => {
})
```